# What HTTP response code should be used when a client misses their chance to accept an offer

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, client-server

I am writing a web application in C#. One piece of functionality is that the server will send out a push notification offering a client the opportunity to do a round of work. The client can accept or refuse this work.

However, if the client takes too long to respond, the server will see this as an implicit refusal and offer the round of work to someone else.

Here is an extract of the controller endpoint on the server, where a client can post it's acceptance of the current round

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostAcceptRound(PersonData accepter){
    Round currentRound = repo.GetCurrentRound();
    if(currentRound.offeredTo.id == accepter.id){
        repo.RoundAccepted(currentRound.id);
        return Request.CreateResponse<String>(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Round has been accepted");
    }
    else{
        //return appropriate response
    }
}
```

My question is: what is the appropriate response for the client taking too long to accept?

My initial reaction was that I should sent a "BadRequest" error response. However, it is not as if a person refusing late is poorly formed request or something that is unexpected. Indeed, it seems as if accepting too late will be a situation that will happen often within the use of this application.

Comment: May be CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout) will work for you? This means client was not reached or busy with other stuff. Let's delegate unit of work to another cleint

Comment: Wait wait... Server sends a push to client? Are you sure HTTP is the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

408 = 'Request Timeout' seems to me to most appropriate.
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html